# Application System

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So i make a application system for a discord server and when testing it the bot worked fine till the questiosn for the application finished and it said application has been sent but it didnt send the application and i got a error saying

`(node:11408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Here is my code The error is on `appsChannel.send(applicationembed);`

```js
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: "apply",
    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {string[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const questions = [
            "What is your IGN currently?",
            "What is your discord Name and Tag?",
            "Why do you want to join the guild?",
            "What games stats are you applying with?",
            "Is there anything else you want to tell us?"
        ];
        let collectCounter = 0;
        let endCounter = 0;

        const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;

        const appStart = await message.author.send(questions[collectCounter++])
        const channel = appStart.channel;

        const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter);
        
        collector.on("collect", () => {
            if(collectCounter < questions.length) {
                channel.send(questions[collectCounter++])
            } else {
                channel.send("You application has been sent!")
                collector.stop("fulfilled")
            }
        })

        const appsChannel = client.channels.cache.get('820355472635985991')
        collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
            if(reason === 'fulfilled') {
                let index = 1;
                const mappedResponses = collected.map((msg) => {
                    return `${index++}) ${questions[endCounter++]}\n-> ${msg.content}`;
                })
                .join('\n\n');
              
           const applicationembed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(
                        message.author.tag,
                        message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: ture })
                    )
                    .setTitle('New Application!')
                    .setDescription(mappedResponses)
                    .setColor('RANDOM')
                    .setTimestamp()
            appsChannel.send(applicationembed);

        }
                
        })
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the channel you're trying to get is not in the cache. It's always best to fetch rather than rely on the cache.

Change your `appsChannel` definition to this.

```
const appsChannel = await client.channels.cache.fetch('820355472635985991');
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you try using await here?

```
const appsChannel = await client.channels.cache.get('820355472635985991')
```

Edit:

```
const applicationembed = await new MessageEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(
                        message.author.tag,
                        message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: ture })
                    )
                    .setTitle('New Application!')
                    .setDescription(mappedResponses)
                    .setColor('RANDOM')
                    .setTimestamp()
            await appsChannel.send(applicationembed);
```

For your async to work:

```
collector.on('end', async (collected, reason) => {
```

Comment: And with adding this as well?
See my edit in my answer.

Comment: it says SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function even though at line 10 it says  run: async (client, message, args) => {

Comment: Hmm I just see it now, but you forgot the brackets on MessageEmbed.
I'll edit my post again :)

Edit: nvm I'm wrong. about the brackets. It's because you're nested in another function that hasn't async. Let me edit my post hang on.

Comment: `Collection#get` does not return a promise niether does creating a new embed. `await` is not needed.

Comment: Why would you need await everywhere? These are not promises.

Comment: Kenji it says the same error and Elitezen it says that `const appsChannel = await client.channels.cache.fetch('820355472635985991');` is not a function

Comment: Kenji it just says send isnt defined

Comment: You require `Client` at the top of your file, but pass in `client` as a `run()` parameter. Please make sure you are using a valid client object. Also please directly comment on my answer for further questions